# Lie derivative acting on a function

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I'm a little confused about Lie derivatives. In fact all that definitions of pull-back and push-forward and one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms and integral curves and so on seems strongly formidable and scary to approach.

My question is very simple, I was studying GR from Sean Carroll's book and I arrived at this equation
$$\Delta_{t}T^{\mu_{1}\cdots\mu_{k}}\,_{\nu_{1}\cdots\nu_{l}}(p)=\phi_{t}^{*}\left[T^{\mu_{1}\cdots\mu_{k}}\,_{\nu_{1}\cdots\nu_{l}}(\phi_{t}(p))\right]-T^{\mu_{1}\cdots\mu_{k}}\,_{\nu_{1}\cdots\nu_{l}}(p),
$$
where $ \phi_{t}$ is integral curve of the vector field $V$ on the manifold (and the definition of these terms could be seen on Appendix B of Carroll's book).

Now we  define Lie derivative to be
$$\mathcal{L}_{V}T^{\mu_{1}\cdots\mu_{k}}\,_{\nu_{1}\cdots\nu_{l}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\Delta_{t}T^{\mu_{1}\cdots\mu_{k}}\,_{\nu_{1}\cdots\nu_{l}}}{t}\right),
$$
so how can I prove that the Lie derivative of a function is just the same as the directional derivative of that function?
I think there should be some relations to simplify composition of maps greatly, but I don't know them.

Does anybody knows a more thorough source for reading the subject?

Comment: Please use LaTeX for all equations, not image files.

Answer (score 6):

For a smooth function $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$, we have $\phi_t^*f:=f\circ \phi_t$. So, by the definition of Lie derivative, pullback and by the chain rule,
\begin{align}
(\mathcal{L}_Vf)(p)&:=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(\phi_t^*f)(p)\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f(\phi_t(p))\\
&=(df)_{\phi_0(p)}\left[\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\phi_t(p)\right]\tag{Chain rule}\\
&=df_{p}[V_p],
\end{align}
where the subscripts denote the point of evaluation of the vector/covector fields, and in the last line I used the fact that $\phi_t$ is the integral flow of the vector field $V$. Since the point $p$ was arbitrary, this shows $\mathcal{L}_Vf=(df)[V]$, as desired. Note that this latter expression is also equal to $V(f)$, the action of the vector field $V$ on the smooth function $f$ (this may be a trivial theorem, or literally the definition, depending on the order of presentation and definitions given in the text).

Comment: Hi, I still have some ambiguities and questions:
1. This version of chain rule that you used, is very strange to me, why it produces a one-form times derivative of flow w.r.t t? Is this special kind of chain rule? could you please explain why this chain rule is correct?

2. I haven't seen this definition of Lie derivative, I just wanted to plug a function in my first equation in the post and then do the limiting. Is this possible?

Comment: @hosseinmohammadi for the first question, this follows from the general chain rule in vector spaces $D(F\circ G)_p=DF_{G(p)}\circ DG_p$. See the first half of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3732024/568204) of mine for more details (and also check Loomis and Sternberg for background info). Actually, depending on presentations and definitions (idk how exactly Carroll does it but) the statement I called "chain rule" may actually end up even being a definition for $df$

Comment: For your second question, you literally have to unwind what I'm saying. $\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(\phi_t^*f)(p)$ **by definition** means $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{(\phi_t^*f)(p)-(\phi_0^*f)(p)}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\Delta_tf(p)}{t}$. This is the most basic definition of derivatives out there; it's just a limit of difference quotients, and it is exactly what you wrote.

Comment: thanks a lot ... that was correct.